# Find all available wireless networks in range, using Java

Tags: java, wireless, platform-independent

I want to list all the wireless networks in range using Java. The application needs to be platform-independent, i.e., it should work on both Windows and Linux. I found answers listing different methods for different operating systems for the same. Is there a way in which this can be done directly in Java regardless of the operating system being used?

Comment: You could write JNI wrappers around the Windows mechanism, the Linux mechanism, the Mac mechanism, and then post them for the world to enjoy. Assuming some don't already exist.

Comment: Sure, if Java had an 802.11 API, which'd take care of the actual Java<->Operating System, but if it doesn't, you're stuck with whatever the underlying OS's native facilities are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, you can use [jWlanScan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwlanscan/). However, you may need to implement your own JNI wrapper for OSes.

Comment: I found [JNIWrapper 3.8.1][1] . Can this be useful for the same? I couldn't understand what it does exactly. Have not worked with JNI ever before..


  [1]: http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/JNIWrapper-Download-72730.html

Comment: You might want to try it out. I personally never heard or used that JNIWrapper.

Comment: I tried adding the jWlanScan library in my netbeans project but am not able to get the required info though the project compiles well. I have added the JAR file under libraries and wrote a main class creating an object of Wireless class. But how do I print all the details. I have not added Wireless.dll provided by them in my libraries.

Comment: Can anyone please tell what are the exact steps to use jwlanscan library and how to call the functions.

Comment: I would really appreciate something like this but written in C++ or even better using QT.